# Strange characters in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

From this morning something strange is happening to my Notepad++ editor. When I press <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd> on the keyboard I get some strange symbols:

[image: screenshot]

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

it's an view option, turn it off via view -> "show end of line"

Comment: On mine it's under View -> Show Symbol -> Show End of Line

Comment: I think it's in different places in different versions. I have version  5.6.6.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you're seeing control characters in your view.
Just for fun, a little bit of [CR/LF history](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html).

Answer (score 1):

You've probably turned on some mode that displays control characters. CR-LF (`\r\n` in C parlance) is the standard end-of-line sequences in Windows.